# How to repeat the last non-null value in the remaining rows in a column after the LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have this situation :

```
 a |  b  | c |
 --+-----+----
 1 | 5   | 1
 2 | 9   | 4
 3 | 15  | null
 4 | 20  | null
```

I would like this:

```
 a |  b  | c |
 --+-----+----
 1 | 5   | 1
 2 | 9   | 4
 3 | 15  | 4
 4 | 20  | 4
```

Comment: just column c or all columns ?

Comment: just column c, but I would like to adapt the query also for other columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a, b, @lastc := IFNULL(c, @lastc) AS c
FROM (yourquery) AS q
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @lastc := 0) AS var_init
```

Replace `yourquery` with the original query that resulted in the table with nulls.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6df85/1)

Comment: I get a column c with all BLOB type.

Comment: Weird. When I try it in sqlfiddle, it's converting C to the ASCII code for the number. I don't know where that's coming from.

Comment: I don't know why I get this results. I tried in MySqlWorkbench.

Comment: I tried again and now it works, but instead to set the variable to NULL must be set to 0. Thanks :D

Comment: I guess there's an issue with inferring the type of the `IFNULL` because there's no schema for the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 select `a`, `b`, CASE WHEN `c` is not null then c else   
       (SELECT  `c`
       FROM tabl1 
       WHERE  `c` IS NOT NULL 
       order by a desc  --// you can use the incremented column here if not a, you can use c
       limit 1) end as c 

 from tabl1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bbe6/4)

this will work if column a is incremented , means numbers will increase only.